# New Foreign Entities Aren't created with Update

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When I add a new item to a virtual collection property of my Entity it'll be added to the database.

For example

```
Loan.Notes.Add(new Note {Subject = "Test"})
```

This will create a new row in Notes table and showing the loanId for the link.

I tried to replicate this exact working functionality for another table. I set a breakpoint right before it hits save and I can see the collection has the `NEW` entity but it won't create. I'm clueless towards why it's working in one scenario and not the other.

Notes saves completely fine, status history doesn't.

```
public void Save()
{
    foreach (var noteDTO in Notes.Where(x => x.NewRecord))
    {
        Loan.Notes.Add(new Note
        {
            Subject  = noteDTO.Subject,
            Comments = noteDTO.Comments,
            Active   = noteDTO.Active,
            Loan     = Loan,
            Loan_Id  = Loan.Id
        });
    }


    foreach (var status in StatusHistory.Where(x => x.Id == 0))
    {
        Loan.StatusHistory.Add(
            new LoanStatusHistory
                {
                    Loan_Id        = Loan.Id,
                    Active         = status.Active,
                    IsCurrent      = status.Current,
                    Date           = status.StatusDate.Value.Date,
                    StatusReason   = status.Reason,
                    LoanStatus_Id  = status.Status_Id.Value,
                    Order          = status.Order.Value,
                    Created        = DateTime.Now,
                    CreatedBy      = CurrentUser.GetInstance().MyUser.Id,
                    Modified       = DateTime.Now,
                    LastModifiedBy = CurrentUser.GetInstance().MyUser.Id
                });
        }             
    }
    UnitOfWork.LoanRepository.Update(Loan);
    UnitOfWork.Save();
}
```

In Notes and Status models I have set there to be a virtual relationship to loan.

```
public virtual Loan Loan { get; set; }
```

In Loan Model I have set there to be a virtual relationship to Notes and Status

```
public virtual ICollection<LoanStatusHistory> StatusHistory { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }
```

I was wondering if anyone could give me suggestions or tips to fix this please.

Comment: Where are you adding the StatusHistory/Notes to the Loan object?  I see you adding the Loan to the StatusHistory/Notes and then never inserting those into the StatusHistory/Notes tables.

Comment: Sorry i copied over update code, make changes at the moment.

Comment: Is your code working for StatusHistory but no for Notes?

Comment: Hi @MarcCals It's working perfectly for Notes not for StatusHistory

Comment: There are is subtle difference between the two, but I don't know if this is the reason without looking how you configurate the relationships with Entity Framework . Notes have Loan property , StatusHistory no.

Comment: Thanks @MarcCals but because it's added it through Loan entity, the Loan property is specified. I can remove Loan = Loan entirely or add it in. Doesn't make a difference.